# Installing Ubuntu 14.04 Inside Windows 8

Tags: system-installation, wubi, windows-8

Installing Ubuntu 14.04 inside Windows 8; can anybody help me? Is it safe to install Ubuntu inside Windows 8? I am not getting info about installing Ubuntu in Windows 8. In Windows 7 we can use Wubi, but what about with Windows 8?

Answer (score 0):

[Wubi is not supported for Windows 8](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2013/04/wubi-advice)  Possible alternatives for you would be dual boot, or installation of Ubuntu in a virtual machine (VMWare or VirtualBox)